# Wrapping a Container in a Column results in overflow

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Consider the following example app:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  double percentageHeight(num percentage) {
    MediaQueryData media = MediaQuery.of(this.context);
    double availableHeight = media.size.height - media.padding.top;

    return availableHeight * percentage / 100;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        // ###### relevant part start ######
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.orange,
            height: percentageHeight(90),
          ),
        ),
        // ###### relevant part end ######
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
          color: Colors.grey,
          elevation: 0,
          notchMargin: 0,
          child: Container(
            height: percentageHeight(10),
            child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[],
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

This works and results in the following output (iPhone 11 Pro (11.6)):

[image]

When I replace the `body` (formerly a `Container` with height 90%) with

```
SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                height: percentageHeight(90),
                color: Colors.orange,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )
```

I get an overflow that looks like this:

[image]

Why does it behave like this? Does a `Column` have an inherent height?

Comment: I ran your code on my PC and didn't get any overflow, albeit I ran it on a Pixel 3XL emulator. You should try wrapping your container in an Expanded Widget, that should fix your overflow issue. And Column doesn't have a defined height. You can read the documentation on api.fluttter.dev to know more.

Comment: When I run it on an iPhone SE, there was also no overflow, only on the 11 pro and 11 max.
Yes, the wrapping it in an `Expanded` works but then the height property is not required anymore. I would like to give exact percentages to my containers so I can control their content more easily.
Of course I can get it to work with `Expanded` but I also would like to understand why it behaves like this